# can Bing Text-to-Speech take a javascript variable value and convert it to speech?

Tags: javascript, azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

I am using Bing text to speech api in javascript and generating random numbers for addition. Just for support I wanted to integrate bing text-to-speech to my code but I am not able to find a documentation on microsoft page which says that you can pass dynamic parameter to api.
By far it is able to to this:

```
var bingClientTTS = newBingSpeech.TTSClient("API KEY");
document.getElementById("speakBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
bingClientTTS.synthesize("5 + 7");
});
```

But when I do this it gives Type error:

```
var randomNum1 = getRandom(),
var randomNum2 = getRandom();
total =randomNum1 + randomNum2;
$( "#question" ).text( randomNum1 + " + " + randomNum2 + "=" );  
document.getElementById("speakBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
bingClientTTS.synthesize(randomNum1.value);
});

TypeError: Cannot read property 'encodeHTML' of undefined
```

Is there any way to pass variable to bing tts api or should I use google tts.

To avoid api calls I have used a javascript client library[github link](https://github.com/davrous/BingSpeech)

Answer (score 0):

If it works with a string, it does not matter how you obtain that string.

Try `randomNum1` instead of `randomNum1.value`.

Comment: What's inside `randomNum1`? Can you console.log that?

Comment: If `syntesize("x")` works, there is absolutely no reason it wouldn't work with a string stored in a JavaScript variable. Whatever you send to BingClient is static, the way you reach what you send to BingClient is dynamic.

Comment: Try `randomNum1.toString()`, you are doing Math with it, so I think it's an integer.

Comment: I tried using integers on their website it works fine

Comment: `toString` worked fine. Only thing is whats written on screen and what it speaks  are both different numbers

Comment: That's a problem in your logic and not related to BingClient.